# Cannot implicitly convert type 'BatchAPI_Demo.Models.SubError' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BatchAPI_Demo.Models.SubError>'

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Model class

```cs
public class ErrorLog
{
    public int CorrelationID { get; set; }
    
    public List<SubError> errors { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Class

```cs
public class SubError
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code

```cs
ErrorLog objError = new ErrorLog();
SubError objsubErr = new SubError();
if (req.Businessunit == "")
{
    objError.CorrelationID = 400;
    objsubErr.source = "Error Occurred";
    objsubErr.description = "Units cannot be blank";

    objError.errors = objsubErr;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objError);
}
```

I am getting error when I assign objSuberr to errors. What could be the solution to assign the source and description value in errors class.
I am quite a newbie. Might b a easy way out, but I am unable to trace it. Any help ,would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to **assign** a singular SubError to a list of SubError.  You can't.  They are different types.  On is a List and the other is a Singular Object so you can't **assign**.

You need to **add** the singular object to the list.

```
objError.errors.Add(objSubErr);
```

In your case, you'll also need to instantiate the list first:

```
objError.errors = new List<SubError>();
objError.errors.Add(objSubErr);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was aware I should assign List but was not able to figure out how. Thanks Neil:)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanatory. You're trying to assign an object of type `SubError` to an object of type `List<SubError>`. If you need to keep a `List` then `objError.errors = objsubError` becomes `objError.errors.Add(objsubError)`.

I don't see where you initialize the `errors` property. In that case, you may use `objError.errors = new List<SubError> { objsubError };` which ensures that the property is initialized *and* it will add the new object to the list.

Comment: I had initialize error property in context file, however I didn't paste the code over here.